# pgfplot log mode and rescale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to specify the following x positions on the x-axis:
0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.16, 0.32. I try to use `xmode = log`, but failed to find a suitable base.
As shown in the image below, currently, the axises are 2^(-7), 2^(-6)....
[image]

I want [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.16, 0.32] appear on the x-axis. Meanwhile, I hope the distance between such points is equal.

If I use `xtick` directly, I get the following figure and do not know how to make the space between ticks meanly.
[image]

Much appreciated if anyone could give me some help.

Comment: Welcome. Do you want the x values as x labels or what do you mean with 'specify x positions'?

Comment: @Excelsior. Yes, I want those values to appear on the x-axis. Meanwhile, I hope the distance between such points is equal.

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far. Maybe you can share the data you want to plot ...

Comment: You can specify your ticks using `xtick={...}` in the `axis` environment. By the way, why aren't you using `semilogaxis` or `loglogaxis`?

Comment: @Excelsior If I use xtick={...}, as you can see in my supplement to this question, the space between ticks becomes different. I do not know `semilogaxis` and `loglogaxis`. I am sorry that I am new to pgfplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the `semilogxaxis` environment in combination with `xtick` and `xticklabels` and this is what I get. Let me know if it suits your purpose.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.txt}
    x   y
    0.00390625  0.25
    0.0078125   0.26
    0.015625    0.27
    0.03125 0.28
    0.0625  0.29
    0.125   0.28
    0.25    0.27
    0.5 0.26
    1   0.25
        
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            xtick={0.01,0.02,0.04,0.08,0.16,0.32},
            xticklabels={0.01,0.02,0.04,0.08,0.16,0.32},
            ]
            
            \addplot[
                mark=o,
                color=blue]
            table[
            x=x, 
            y=y,
            ]
            {test.txt};
            
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you most sincerely!